# How can I let individual users import their own external blog feeds in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-feeds

So, I'm trying to build a 'blog gateway' in Drupal 7 that will let users add/edit/remove feeds from their own external sites to a collective stream for rating, comments etc.

The site should do something along the lines of:

1. Let the user add a URL for their feed via the registration form
2. Import the most recent posts from the feed upon registration (and afterwards continually).
3. Create a node for each item in the feed, which can be rated by other users.
4. Create lists from these nodes.

Okay, so Views in combination with the Feeds module can do most of this (import feeds, create nodes for each item and create lists). I've managed to allow users to import feeds 'manually' using the Feeds module.

The problems are that I can't find a way to limit the number of feeds a user can import, and I can't figure out how to make a URL from the registration form the basis of an import.

I've been trying to solve these problems using the Rules module, but with no results.

Methinks something along the lines of the Profile Blog Information module could do the trick, but it's only available for Drupal 6 and doesn't work with the Feeds module.

Any thoughts on solutions or alternatives?

Comment: Hi @Ovenfra, so if my answer worked for you, you could may be mark it as right so that it could be good reference for others when they look this question up. If it didn't work, you can let me know and I'll review it. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @AmarRavikumar! First of all, thank you so much for your answer! I really do appreciate it, and I apologize for not responding until now. Unfortunately, I've had to focus on other projects since I posted the question, so I've had to postpone trying it out. I'll check it out as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find a way to limit the number of feeds a user can import

If you use the default settings of the Feeds module, you should have a "Feed" content type already. So, if you want to control the number of "feeds" a user can import, http://drupal.org/project/node_limit should do the trick, I think. It'll help you set the number of nodes of the "Feed" content type that a user can *create*  (which should be the same thing, right?)

> how to make a URL from the registration form the basis of an import

Now, I'm going to suggest a custom module route here. It should do the trick but you may/may not want to add a custom module depending on the nature of your project/your level of expertise with Drupal.

1. Add a URL field (probably an instance of the [URL field type](http://drupal.org/project/url)) to the user profile. Check to allow it to be shown in the registration form. Lets say we call it `feed_url`.
2. Implement [hook_user_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7)() which is called when a new user is added to the site:

   ```
   /**
    * Implements hook_user_insert().
    */
   function MY_MODULE_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
     if (isset($edit['feed_url'])) {
       $index = array('feed_url', LANGUAGE_NONE, 'value');
       // Get the feed URL from the registration form values.
       $feed_url = drupal_array_get_nested_value($edit, $index);
       if (!empty($feed_url)) {
         // Create a new feed on behalf of the user
         _MY_MODULE_create_feed($feed_url, $account->uid);
       }
     }
   }

   /**
    * Creates a new feed on behalf of a user.
    *
    * @param string $url
    *   Feed URL
    * @param numeric $uid
    *   {users}.uid of the user for whom this feed is being created.
    */
   function _MY_MODULE_create_feed($url, $uid) {
     // @todo Add more validations here
     $node = new stdClass();
     $node->uid = $uid;
     $node->type = 'feed';
     $node->feeds['FeedsHTTPFetcher']['source'] = $url;
     $node->language = language_default('language');
     node_save($node);
   }
   ```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand: "how to make a URL from the registration form the basis of an import" though.

Comment: If anyone finds this in the future, there's a typo on line 5 which results in a syntax error. One missing `)` in the if statement. The first line in the function `MY_MODULE_user_insert`.

Comment: @hampusn Right you are. Fixed.

Comment: Cheers :) Developers would probably find it, but copy/paste:ers might not.